# Tab in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I am making a social website that each user can view his own or other user's profile. I created a user controller to handle the identity and blog, status, profile controller to retrieve information. My question is how can I make the three sub controllers ( blog, status, profile) under the user controller, like a tab view?

Comment: What do you mean about sub controller? How controller can be like a tab view?

Comment: Hi I want it like: {user} [{blog}, {status}, {profile}]. User contain the target user's first name and last name, and is always displayed above the content of the other three controllers.

Comment: when you go to stackoverflow's home your user name is on the top and below there are top question tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have Tabs in your application you should pick first an ajax framework to create andload content into them:

Assuming you are willing to use jquery: 
Tabs supports loading tab content via Ajax in an unobtrusive manner.

The HTML you need is slightly different from the one that is used for static tabs: A list of links pointing to existing resources (from where the content gets loaded) and no additional containers at all (unobtrusive!). The containers' markup is going to be created on the fly:

```
<div id="example">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="/user/id/1/mode/simple"><span>USER</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="/blog/id/1/mode/simple"><span>his blogs</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="/theotherthing/id/1/mode/simple"><span>Whatever</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

For more info: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Events

And the tab content will be loaded through those "controllers" which are in fact generating view scripts.

To disable the layout on your views which should be integrated inside the Tabs-panels, if the mode is simple, you can add in ZF1

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```